# Running a method once a week at a particular time

Tags: java, scheduler

I looked all over the place. I looked through Timers and Quartz and I am still confused.

I have a huge class performing different methods. One of those methods is a synchronized method:

```
  public void onSynch()
  {
    String environment = validateEnvironment(env2);
    if (environment == null) return;
    try
    {
        RAT.synchronize(environment);
        onSelectEnv();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
// TODO: tell user, log
    }   
  }
```

I need to be able to create a timer that triggers this method alone once a week at a particular time, every Friday and 3:00 PM for example.
I cannot create separate classes.

I need to be able to put the scheduler inside of this method, or create another method next to it that would create a scheduler and run that sync method.

Comment: Why not use cron if you are in linux  or schedule an activity if you are using windows?

Comment: "Cannot create separate classes"? That is an absurd restriction. mserioli's suggestions are your best bet, but they require much more than just a class. They require what amounts to a separate application (with shared code) to be scheduled.

Comment: Thank you guys. So there is no way to run this method every 7 days using Quartz?

Comment: You can use a thread that check every tot seconds if it could execute your method..

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest to use `QUARTZ` or `Spring Batch` for scheduler job.

Try below `Quartz Example`.
Reference : [CronTrigger Tutorial](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/tutorials/crontrigger), [Example](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.2.x/tutorials/)

YourJob.java

```
public class YourJob implements Job {
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
        //here your operation
    }   
}
```

MySchedule.java

```
public class MySchedule {
    public void startUp() throws Exception {
        SchedulerFactory sf = new StdSchedulerFactory();
        Scheduler scheduler = sf.getScheduler();

        JobDetail yourJob = JobBuilder.newJob(YourJob.class).withIdentity("job1", "group1").build();

        /*Run every 30 seconds on Weekdays (Monday through Friday)*/
        Trigger trigger_1 = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
                .withIdentity("trigger1", "group1")
                .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0,30 * * ? * MON-FRI"))
                .build();

        /*Run at 10am on the 1st and 15th days of the month*/
        Trigger trigger_2 = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
                .withIdentity("trigger2", "group1")
                .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0 0 10am 1,15 * ?"))
                .build();

        /*Run at 3:30PM of every friday f month*/
        Trigger trigger_3 = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
                .withIdentity("trigger3", "group1")
                .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0 18 30 ? * 6"))
                .build();

        scheduler.start();

        scheduler.scheduleJob(yourJob, trigger_1);
        scheduler.scheduleJob(yourJob, trigger_2);
        scheduler.scheduleJob(yourJob, trigger_3);

    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't /*Run at 3:30PM of every Friday of month*/ be: "0 30 15 ? * 6"?